# Android emulator does not boot on Ubuntu 15.04 (64bit)

Tags: emulation, boot

When I start the emulator, the "phone" shows only a black screen. Nothing more happens. No loading, no pixels, no application nothing. Just a black screen.

Based on other forums i tried:

- restart several times
- install mesagl
- install more c++ libs
- start emulator without android studio
- enable or disable "Use host gpu" option
- limit emulator ram to 768mbyte
- delete and recreate virtual device with several other api and abi
- reinstall nvidia closed driver

Non of these helped.
Any other suggestions?